how to disable Function utf8_encode() is deprecated in PHP?
I just upgraded to php 8.3.7 on a windows machine and upon trying to access the admin panel of my php application I get this error;
Whoops \ Exception \ ErrorException (E_DEPRECATED)
Function utf8_encode() is deprecated

$json_response = false;
if ($updater_content !== false) {
    $json_response = json_decode(utf8_encode($updater_content), true);
}

this error was not showing up in the previous version and is coming from the build_check_updates.php file. I have tried replacing it with mb_convert_encoding but it's not working in my case. is there a way to disable this error?
-replaced utf8_encode with mb_convert_decoding "UTF-8" however it's not working in my case. (gives syntax errors and breaks the whole file.) Also upgraded php with chocolatey but error persists.

If you really need to convert the encoding to utf 8 then mb_convert_decoding is what to use. If you get a syntax error then share the code that you are attempting to use it because the fix might be simple

It might be worth reading the “Usage” section of the RFC that resulted in the removal of the function, to see if one of your cases has alternative ways. That said, this is a deprecation notice, not an error. The function will be removed, probably in PHP 9, but you can ignore the deprecation notice for now, nothing should break. I’d also recommend reading the RFC and understand what the function does, why it is poorly named and why it is being removed, and adjust your code accordingly.

Is $updater_content encoded in ISO-8859-1?

Replaced utf8_encode() with this but gives the error call to undefined function:   $json_response = json_decode(mb_convert_decoding($string,'UTF-8','ISO-8859-1')($updater_content), true);
}

It's mb_convert_encoding, not mb_convert_decoding.

It also is json_decode(mb_convert_encoding($updater_content,'UTF-8','ISO-8859-1'), true);

As already pointed out, the whole conversion does not make any sense unless you positively know that $updater_content is encoded using ISO-8859-1. There's a chance that utf8_encode() was either unnecessary or harmful. The function is deprecated because of its misleading name: people didn't care to read what it actually does, and expected it to magically fix encoding problems.
